# Flask test form submission

Tags: python, flask

Im trying to write a test for some form that writes data to my database.
I don't know why it doesn't work.

route:

> ```
> @admin.route('/session/new', methods=['POST', 'GET']) @login_required def new_session():
> form = AddSession()
> if form.validate_on_submit():
>     print(form.name.data)
>     print(request)
>     add_session = Session(name=form.name.data,
>                           start_date=form.start_date.data,
>                           end_date=form.end_date.data)
>     db.session.add(add_session)
>     db.session.commit()
>     flash('A session has been successfully added!', 'success')
>     return redirect(url_for('admin.sessions_overview'))
>
> return render_template('sessions/new_session.html', title='Add Session', form=form)
> ```

test:

> class FlaskClientTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
>
> ```
> def setUp(self):
>     self.app = create_app('testing')
>     self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
>     self.app_context.push()
>     db.create_all()
>     populate_db(db)
>     self.client = self.app.test_client(use_cookies=True)
>
> def tearDown(self):
>     db.session.remove()
>     db.drop_all()
>     self.app_context.pop()
>
> def test_new_session(self):
>     response = self.client.post('/login', data={
>         'username': 'joshn',
>         'password': '123'
>     }, follow_redirects=True)
>     self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
>
>     session_data = {
>         'name': 'test_session',
>         'start_date': date(2019, 7, 20),
>         'end_date': date(2019, 7, 21)
>     }
>     response = self.client.post('/session/new', data={
>         'name': 'test_session',
>         'start_date': date(2019, 7, 20),
>         'end_date': date(2019, 7, 21)
>     })
>
>     self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, "Form wasn't submitted")  # Checks the form submission was valid
>
>     test_s = Session.query.filter_by(name='test_session').first()
>     self.assertIsNotNone(test_s, "Session wasn't added to database")
>
>     self.assertEqual(session_data['name'], test_s.name, "Data wasn't written properly to db")
>     self.assertEqual(session_data['start_date'], test_s.start_date, "Data wasn't written properly to db")
>     self.assertEqual(session_data['end_date'], test_s.end_date, "Data wasn't written properly to db")
> ```

error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tests/test_admin.py", line
>   56, in test_new_session
>       self.assertIsNotNone(test_s, "Session wasn't added to database") AssertionError: unexpectedly None : Session wasn't added to database

EDIT: ok i added an else to the route, but now i get a response code 400,
and when i checked the post request was empty.

The updated route:

```
def new_session():
    form = AddSession()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.name.data)
        print(request)
        add_session = Session(name=form.name.data,
                              start_date=form.start_date.data,
                              end_date=form.end_date.data)
        db.session.add(add_session)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('A session has been successfully added!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('admin.sessions_overview'))
    else:
        print(request.method)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            args = request.args
            print(args)
            add_session = Session(name=args['name'],
                                  start_date=args['start_date'],
                                  end_date=args['end_date'])
            db.session.add(add_session)
            db.session.commit()
            return Response(status=302)

    return render_template('sessions/new_session.html', title='Add Session', form=form)
```

The message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_admin.py", line 53, in test_new_session
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302, "Form wasn't submitted")  # Checks the form submission was valid
AssertionError: 400 != 302 : Form wasn't submitted
```

Answer (score 0):

If form is not validated on submit, `new_session()` will return `render_template` which returns `200` as `status_code`

You need an `else` to check when the form is not validated. There might be for example a csrf token as a hidden input or anything else and you have to display form errors to know the reason.